# Getting TypeError when try to run the python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following code is used to get the input from the user and then print out the odd numbers in the user input

```
list2 = [ list2 for list2 in input("list").split(",")]

odd_nos = [ num for num in list2 if num % 2 !=0]

print ("Odd numbers in the list: ",odd_nos)
```

BUT, I run into the following error when trying to run above piece of code

```
odd_nos =[ num for num in list2 if num % 2 !=0]

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Appreciate if you can help me on this.

Comment: A suggestion would be to add a short description of what you are trying to do.  Are you taking an input of numbers and just keeping the odd numbers from the inputted list?

Comment: Try: odd_nos = [int(x) for x in input('Enter list').split(',') if int(x) % 2]

Comment: K bro can u explain the comment you hve done in this section.i am new to python.

Comment: The don't forget comment?  That's more of pointing out a feature of stack overflow where the poster should vote on an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
list2 = [int(list2) for list2 in lst.split(",")]
odd_nos = [ num for num in list2 if num % 2 !=0]
print ("Odd numbers in the list: ",odd_nos)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix--needed int(num), since num is a string.

```
list2 = [ list2 for list2 in input("list").split(",")]
odd_nos = [ int(num) for num in list2 if int(num) % 2 !=0]
print ("Odd numbers in the list: ",odd_nos)
```

Or one-liner

```
odd_nos = [int(x) for x in input('Enter list').split(',') if int(x) % 2]
```